extract key value pairs and convert to json
Given:
PowerShell 5.1
Text data file
I need to get those key value pairs (delimited by ":") and convert them to json. I was thinking getting the colons via regex "\s:\s" then replace with "=" sign and then turn into hashtable, and then use ConvertTo-Json
Would this be a good design?
Data text file
some unimportant variables

some unimportant variables - c:\blah

some unimportant variables

List keys.

key1 : value1
key2 : value2

List keys complete.

some unimportant variables


Asking if it is a good design is subjective and will lead to opinionated answers. This site is all about objective programming questions and answers, so ideally you should reformulate your question.

SO is not a good place for design questions. As written, this question may attract downvotes and votes to close.

As with you your previous question, please give some background. Are these files completely custom made or are the related to a specific environment (e.g. Git output)? Even in case they are custom made, I would try to commit to an existing format which has the most corresponding factors where you could leverage from existing convertors or parsers.

You're probably looking for something like [regex]::Matches($text, '(?m)^\w+\s?:\s?\w+').Value -replace '(?<!:.*):', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData | ConvertTo-Json
